how to get a callback from discord desktop app
I am developing this web application that has a login to the workspace but after the user logs in successfully I want to make sure that he is running the discord app installed on his pc and is logged in there with the same email that he used previously to login to my web app and then directs him to the workspace. Executing the discord app installed on the pc when he logs in successfully wasn't a tough task to do but I have no idea how to check that the email he logged in with to discord is the same that he used to login to my web app so how can I achieve a communication between my web app and the discord desktop app and get callbacks from the discord app. I am using node js and mongo db
I heard about the Oauth2 but that doesn't solve my problem I don't want the user to connect to my web app using his discord credentials instead I want to make sure that after successufully logging in to my web app he runs the discord app installed on his pc with the same email he used previously to login to my web app
